# Spark S3 CSV read returns org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException

Tags: csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I see several posts here and in a Google search for *org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException* 
but most deal with HDFS files or trapping errors.  My issue is that while I can read a CSV file from spark-shell, running it from a compiled JAR constantly returns an *org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException* error.

The rough process of the jar:
1. read from JSON documents in S3 (this works)
2. read from parquet files in S3 (this also succeeds)
3. write a result of a query against #1 and #2 to a parquet file in S3 (also succeeds)
4. read a configuration csv file from the same bucket #3 is written to. (this fails)

These are the various approaches that I have tried in code:

```
1. val osRDD = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3://bucket/path/")
2. val osRDD = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("s3://bucket/path/")
```

All variations of the two above with s3, s3a and s3n prefixes work fine from the REPL but inside a JAR they return this:
*org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: s3://bucket/path/eventsByOS.csv*
So, it found the file but can't read it.

Thinking this was a permissions issue, I have tried:

```
a. export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access key> and export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret> from the Linux prompt.  With Spark 2 this has been sufficient to provide us access to the S3 folders up until now.
b. .config("fs.s3.access.key", <access>)
.config("fs.s3.secret.key", <secret>)
.config("fs.s3n.access.key", <access>)
.config("fs.s3n.secret.key", <secret>)
.config("fs.s3a.access.key", <access>)
.config("fs.s3a.secret.key", <secret>)
```

Before this failure, the code reads from parquet files located in the same bucket and writes parquet files to the same bucket.  The CSV file is only 4.8 KB in size.

Any ideas why this is failing?

Thanks!

Adding stack trace:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:253)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:201)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:281)
org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1332)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1326)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1367)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1366)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.findFirstLine(CSVFileFormat.scala:206)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.inferSchema(CSVFileFormat.scala:60)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:183)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:415)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:352)
```

Comment: what's the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @SteveLoughran :-)

Answer (score 0):

nothing springs out when I paste that stack into the IDE, but I'm looking at a later version of Hadoop and can't currently switch to older ones.

1. Have a look at [these instructions](https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-spark/)
2. That landsat gz file is actually a CSV file you can try to read in; it's the one we generally use for testing because its there and free to use. Start by seeing if you can work with it.
3. If using spark 2.0, use spark's own CSV package.
4. Do use S3a, not the others.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That's a great set of instructions.  While they didn't help read the CSV, they do help me write files faster. The spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version 2 alone accounts for a huge improvement.

Comment: yeah, renames a a  killer. Got some ongoing work to fix that, [HADOOP-13786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13786); not ready for use, but you'd be welcome to help test it as it gets closer to release.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the specific Hadoop configuration for the appropriate method (s3 in the example here).  The odd thing is that the above security works for everything in Spark 2.0 EXCEPT reading the CSV.

This code solved my problem using S3.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", p.aws_accessKey)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey",p.aws_secretKey)
```